# Cannot access req.files from req object using multer

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, angular-material, multer

I am trying to upload a file to the server using NodeJs script. I am trying the following things.

**HTML**

```
<md-tab label="Upload log">
    <md-content class="md-padding" id="popupContainer" ng-cloak>
        <h4>Upload a zip file</h4>
            <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
                <md-input-container class="md-block" flex>
                    <label>Source</label>
                    <md-select name="source" ng-model="log.source" ng-click="getSources()">
                        <md-option ng-repeat="source in sourceInfo" value="{{source.sourceCode}}">{{source.sourceName}}</md-option>
                    </md-select>
                </md-input-container>
                <br>
                <md-input-container class="md-block">
                    <label>Select Batch</label>
                    <input required type="number" step="any" name="rate" ng-model="log.batch" min="1" max="100"/>
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container class="md-block">
                    <label>Enter your comments about the log files</label>
                    <textarea ng-readonly="false" ng-model="log.comment" md-maxlength="100" rows="3" md-select-on-focus></textarea>
                </md-input-container>
                <div ng-if="status" id="status">
                    <b layout="row" layout-align="center center" class="md-padding">{{status}}</b>
                </div>
                <input type="file" file-model="log.file" name="inputFile"/>
                <button ng-click="uploadFiles()">Upload</button>
                {{log}}
                <p> </p>
            </form>
    </md-content>
</md-tab>
```

**Directive**

```
var logApp = angular.module('logAnalysisApp', ['ngMaterial', 'lfNgMdFileInput', 'ngRoute', 'ngMessages']);
logApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$compileProvider', '$mdThemingProvider', function ($routeProvider, $compileProvider, $mdThemingProvider) {
            $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
            $routeProvider
            .when('/login', {
                templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                controller: 'loginControl'
            })
            .when('/register', {
                templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
                controller: 'registerControl'
            })
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'views/filemenu.html',
                controller: 'fileUploadCtrl'
            })
            .when('/admin', {
                templateUrl: 'views/adminpanel.html',
                controller: 'adminCtrl'
            })
            .when('/totalreport', {
                templateUrl: 'views/total.html',
                controller: 'totalCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/login'
            });
        }
    ])

logApp.constant('config', {
    apiUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
    serverUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
})

logApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                    var modelSetter = model.assign;

                    element.bind('change', function () {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                        });
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

**Controller**

```
logApp.controller('fileUploadCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $timeout, $location, $http, config) {
    $scope.log = {};
    $scope.uploadFiles = function () {

        console.log($scope.log);

        var uploadUrl = "http://localhost:3000/testRef";

        var fd = new FormData();
        for (var key in $scope.log)
            fd.append(key, $scope.log[key]);
        for (var pair of fd.entries()) {
            console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
        }
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.indentity,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }
        })
        .success(function () {
            console.log("success!!");
        })
        .error(function () {
            console.log("error!!");
        });
    };
});
```

**ServerSide Coding**

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });
app.post('/testRef', upload.any("inputFile"), function(request, response) {

    console.log(request.files)
    console.log(request.body)
    response.send("Done")
});
```

When I trying to see the `request.files` in the console, it is showing blank array, and `request.body` as a blank object. But in the client log when I am printing `$scope.log` it is showing the appropriate content and when iterating through the **FormData** variable I am seeing the desired data which I am sending. Also, in the html when I am printing the `{{log}}` the file data is not getting populated.

Any type of help is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: @kumbhaniBhavesh: I am getting `req.body` as an empty object. So, trying `req.body.file` might not help.

Answer (score 0):

give a name to form and access req.file("filename")

Comment: It says, req.file is not a function.

Comment: have you given name to form and accessed request.file("fileName")

Comment: `<form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()" name="logInputForm"></form>` is my new form and server code is `console.log(request.file("logInputForm"))`

Comment: just once try with loginputform

Comment: Can you please exactly tell what should I try. Because I am getting a bit confused.

Comment: change the form name to "loginputform"

Comment: Same, it is not working. The `req.body` is still a blank object and `req.file` is undefined and `req.files` is an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add header `'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'`.

Use `req.files[0]` since you have `upload.any('inputFile')` in your server code.

Answer (score 0):

I too have faced the same problem but Thats how our browser works, it's impossible to fix in multer.

A fix for this is to use javascript on the client side to catch the submit event and instead submit using FormData and ordering the fields so that the input data is before any files.

This trick worked for me